# Gazebo: how to control robots models?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I see a bunch of robots model in Gazebo and I wonder if it is possible to control them. I read the tutorial explaining how to adapt a robot model to do that. Since there are many models in Gazebo, they could be delivered with everything required to manipulate them.

I did not find any clue to do that.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67472/gazebo:-how-to-control-robots-models?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-09**:
Hi Arn-O, I am thinking of using turtlebot on Gazebo. As I am new to Gazebo; initially I thought that for turtlebot 2D navigation stack is already set up and we can control everything from rviz. Does we need to write code for moving the turtlebot? Do you know any robot in Gazebo-Ros for which 2D navigation stack is already tuned properly?

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-11-09**:
Hi. Sorry, I can't help. By controlling I only meant to move the joints one by one, far from the navigation stack. It looks like everything of ROS has been applied to the PR2, the home brew robot. And you probably do not need Gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo questions have to be asked on the gazebo answers forum.
But look at http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#Controlling_a_Robot_2 for instance.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2017-04-19**:
This link does not work. Can you re-guide me to the correct link? Thanks in advance